# identify object property by placement in object

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you identify an object by its place in the object.

```
myObj.b = 2
```

can I go somethiong like `myObj[1] to show 2 also`?

```
var myObj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: 4,
    e: 5,
    f: 6
}
```

Comment: a:1 not a:1: --> myObj.b

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this is not possible. An object property has no position as objects are not ordered.

You have to choose between:

- Arrays: Consecutive keys from the range `[0..length)`, in order.
- Objects: Arbitrary keys, no guaranteed order.

A possible workaround would be creating both an object and an array and then using the object for key-based access and the array for index-based. You could then use the array to get the index(es) for a given value.

Comment: Arrays are ordered.  Object properties do not have a specific order.

Comment: True, but with arrays he'd lose the ability to use arbitrary keys.

Comment: You must choose one or the other.  You either want order or you want access by key or you need to build a lot more complicated data structure that lets you use either.  FYI, I upvoted and thought I was adding to your answer, not disputing it.

Comment: @jfriend00: Arrays aren't ordered. We just think of them being ordered because we do loops like `for (i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)`. But there's nothing actually intrisically ordered about an array in JavaScript.

Comment: You can define an order. Object properties have names and you can collate them as you wish.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: You can put them in an array in sorted order. But the object keys themselves do not have a specific order.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, provide alternative solution and I'll remove downvote.  There are other ways of doing what he's asking for.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Array keys are not necessary consecutive, nor are arrays intrinsically ordered; it's merely our treatment of them that makes them ordered (or not).

Comment: @ThiefMaster Exactly. Implementing his request requires constructing a sorted array with references to the object's properties. Inefficient, but not impossible.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - why are you arguing a semantic issue when you know exactly what point I'm making.  Arrays give you ordered access by numerical index.  Objects do not.  The OP needs to pick access by numeric index or by a string key or implement a compound data structure or helper functions that allows both.

Comment: And ugly to keep in sync. Besides that, while downvotes can be given out for pretty much any reason, I consider it pretty inappropriate to downvote an answer that perfectly answers the question just because it doesn't include a hacky way to circumvent it.

Comment: @jfriend00: I'm pointing it out because it's a misconception, and a common one. Agreed that the OP needs to define an order and use it. (You can, of course, use both numeric and non-numeric keys on an array, but there's a fair bit of maintenance required).

Comment: @ThiefMaster A solution is a solution. "Impossible" is not a term to be used lightly.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: They are. `var foo=[]; foo[10] = 'hello';` will cause the array to contain 10 `undefined` values before `hello`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: True, I'd probably change the wording slightly: *"You can't do that with your object as defined"*, something like that. But it's a minor point.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, you're free to disagree with me, and I'm free to leave the downvote in place.  The objective of SO should be to solve problems, not answer questions.  Besides, you still have 5 upvotes.  Surely that will satisfy your reputation lust?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - arrays provide sequential access by numeric index.  To me that's an ordered data structure.  I don't care how the language underneath stores the data.  To the language, the data is available in a strict order.  That's ordered.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: No, it won't, that's a common misconception. More: *[A myth of arrays](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html)* and [spec §15.4](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4).

Comment: It's sparse but still adds to the `length` of the array.

Comment: @jfriend00: There's exactly as much order to an array using "numeric" indexes as to an object that you use the keys `"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"`, etc. with. Convention, a couple of functions that support the convention (`splice`, for instance), and that's all. Understanding how JavaScript's arrays *actually* work is quite useful. But I won't bang on about it. :-)

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Yes, because `length` gets set when properties whose names are all-numeric are created, if the numeric value of that property name is equal to or greater than the previous value of `length`. But your `foo` array has precisely **one** entry, for the key `"10"`.

Comment: @ThiefMaster - I know the underlying details.  Feel free to code ordered sets of data with numerical indexes on a javascript object if you want to.  I won't consider that very readable code and won't find very many helpful methods on the object for letting me manipulate that data like the Array object has.  I prefer to use Arrays and their methods for ordered data structures.  If you want to profer doing it differently go ahead, but I'll be done with this dumb side argument that has nothing to do with the OP's question and is attacking a linguistic detail rather than a helpful point.

Comment: @jfriend00: (I think you meant that last comment to be directed at me.) I didn't know we were having an *argument*. I didn't intend it to be one. Best,

Answer (score 2):

No, myObj[1] will result in undefined. Object literals are hash maps (key, value stores), which do not support indexed based access. This is so because items in a hash do not have a predictable order of iteration.

What you can do, to get the flavor of an index going with your object fields, is:(in jQuery)

```
$.each(myObj, function(index, element) {
    console.log(index + ' : ' + element)
});
```

In plain javascript, you could iterate over the fields using a for in loop, as shown:

```
for (key in myObj) {
   console.log(key);
   console.log(myObj[key]);
}
```

(Note: Your literal has syntax errors).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ultimately the same thing in the end, since until javascript handles JSON, it is simply a string.  When javascript handles it, it gets interpreted as a javascript object.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Of course, corrected. Bad terminology can be a dangerous thing.

Comment: @Neil: Er, no, JSON is not ultimately the same thing as an object initializer (literal). JSON has a much simpler syntax, which is a *subset* of object initializer syntax. `{foo: 42}`, `{'foo': 42}`, `{"foo": undefined}`, and `{1: 42}` are all valid object initializers, but invalid JSON.

Comment: By the time you get it, it's Javascript, @T.J.Crowder, not JSON.  There is nothing you can do to that "JSON" that you couldn't do already in Javascript because it's not some language you're parsing, it's a subset of Javascript or otherwise Javascript wouldn't know how to interpret JSON without first converting it to a Javascript object.  By "same thing" I mean, ultimately you're dealing with a javascript object in javascript, not a JSON object in javascript.

Comment: @Neil: The point is that there isn't, and never was, any JSON in the question or answer. There were object initializers, but never any JSON. But refactor.me has long since updated the offending terminology, and apparently (seeing that) I've long since removed my comment to him you were replying to.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I was replying to you, actually, not refactor.me.  I don't think anything constructive can come from arguing any longer anyway.